# Excel formatting integer from CSV

Tags: microsoft-excel

I exported a CSV from my site. But when I open the file in Excel all the integers format change from `164.9500` to `1.649.500`.

It's really annoying, **does anyone know how to disable this to keep the source format?**

Comment: What language and regional setting are you using? Are the "integers" in your source CSV just numbers, or do they have separator symbols for thousands or the Indian numbering system?

Comment: @teylyn This is exactly how they are in the CSV `,"164.9500",`.

Comment: What is the decimal symbol in your computer settings?  Is it the dot? It seems as if Excel here uses the dot as the Thousand separator., but you want the dot as the decimal symbol. If the CSV file does not use the same convention for decimal symbol and thousand separator, you need to use the Import Wizard to set it straight.

Comment: ... and by the way, if it has a decimal character, it is not an integer. `164.9500` is not an integer in any notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Import Wizard from within Excel (instead of opening the CSV file with File > Open), you can specify each column's data format in step 3 of the wizard and tell Excel how to interpret the data.

Click Data > From Text and select the CSV file. Then in step 3 select the column and specify the format for the column.